# Writing blocks of colour using PIL from list of True/False values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a function which takes a list and a size as arguments, where the list should contain true/false values, like so:

```
theList = [[True, False], [False, True]]
```

It should use these to create a PNG image, with squares of black/white of the specified size (in this case 30x30 squares), in the form:

```
WHITE BLACK
BLACK WHITE
```

My code for this is:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def writeToPNG(theList, blocksize = 30.0):
    length = len(theList[0]) * int(blocksize)
    height = len(theList) * int(blocksize)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (length, height), (0, 0, 0))
    img.putdata(theList, blocksize) # blocksize is 30.0

    i = 1
    while True:
        try:
            img.save('image.png')
            break
        except:
            img.save('image_%i.png' % i)
        i += 1

def makeColour(lizt):
    ## Converts a two dimensional list with True/False
    ## Into a     two dimensional tuple w/ Black/White

    for i in range(0, len(lizt)):
        for j in range(0, len(lizt[i])):
            lizt[i][j] = (255, 255, 255) if (lizt[i][j] == True) else (0, 0, 0)

    newArray = [] # Temporarily is list so is mutable
    for a in lizt:
        newArray.append(tuple(a))
    return tuple(newArray) # Made into a tuple before returning

theList = [[True, False],
[False, True]]
theTuple = makeColour(theList)
writeToPNG(theTuple)
```

However, this does not work. I receive an error, saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "...\main.py", line 19, in writeToPNG
        img.putdata(theList, blocksize)
    File "...\python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1581, in putdata
        self.im.putdata(data, scale, offset)
TypeError: function takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

This error is confusing to me. I tried giving it the third argument as 0.0, and it still gave the exact same error (saying 2 arguments were given, even though I'd given three).

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: https://kite.com/python/docs/PIL.Image.Image.putdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't work because `putdata()` expects a list of colors (tuples) and not a list of rows of colors, which is what you have. Instead of using `putdata()`, you can consider using `ImageDraw` to draw your squares. Here is the updated `writeToPNG` method:

```
def writeToPNG(theList, blocksize = 30):
    length = len(theList[0]) * int(blocksize)
    height = len(theList) * int(blocksize)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (length, height), (0, 0, 0))

    image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, 'RGB')
    pix = img.load()
    for i in range(len(theList)):
        for j in range(len(theList[0])):
            y = i * blocksize
            x = j * blocksize
            image_draw.polygon([(x, y), (x, y+blocksize), (x+blocksize, y+blocksize), (x+blocksize, y)], fill=theList[i][j])

    img.save('image.png')
```

Running this will create this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj6Dc.png).

Comment: Okay, thank you, that does what I need. It writes the blocks going down then right (instead of right then down) though but thinking about it that's to be expected, and all that needs to be done is to swap the i and j around when drawing.